# Partition Help - /dev/sda1 is apparently in use by the system; will not make a filesystem here

Tags: partitioning, filesystems, centos-7

First time post on here. I'm studying for the LFCS course so I'm relatively new to Linux sysadmin, so apologies if this is an obvious question.

I'm having a very frustrating issue that has had me stuck for a few days. I've searched high and low on this site and across google and have yet to find an answer that relates to my exact problem.

I'm doing a little project on my own CentOS 7 VM , I'm setting up Kibana and Elastic search. 
Firstly - I'm setting up a partition on my HD for this, and have created a partition with no problem using fdisk. When i write the new partition to table , I always get the error that tables did not update correctly. But after running partprobe, this resolves this. 
Next it's time to put the file system on the new partition, but here is where I have the problem , i always get this error - /dev/sda1 is apparently in use by the system; will not make a filesystem here!

```
# lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM    SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0   24.5G  0 disk
└─sda1   8:1    0 1023.8M  0 part
sdb      8:16   0    512M  0 disk [SWAP]

# mkfs -t ext4 /dev/sda1
mke2fs 1.42.9 (28-Dec-2013)
/dev/sda1 is apparently in use by the system; will not make a filesystem here!
#
```

I have read similar posts and many answers include checking to see if raid info is stored on the disk, but that is definitely not the case with my VM.

The disk is also unmounted and def does not have a filesystem on it :-

```
# file -sL /dev/sda1
/dev/sda1: data#
```

Any help or ideas anyone has would be gratefully received. I'm pulling my hair out here! Many Thanks :)

Comment: Does the output of `mount` list `/dev/sda1` as mounted? ... for example as your root filesystem?

Comment: What app are you trying to create and run that VM?

Comment: @Attie - when i run the 'mount' command - the output does not mention '/dev/sda1' the only part that is mnetioned is the rest of that disk '/dev/sda on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)'

Comment: @jluizsouzadev - sorry not 100% sure what you mean - do you mean what app am i running the VM from?

Comment: Yep, I do. [Virtualbox](https://www.virtualbox.org)?

Comment: @jluizsouzadev - Linode

Answer (score 1):

Based on your response:

> When I run the `mount`, the output does not mention `/dev/sda1` the only part that is mentioned is the rest of that disk:
>
> ```
> /dev/sda on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)
> ```

In this case, it looks like when you originally installed the operating system, you put a filesystem on `/dev/sda` with no partition table or any partitions - i.e: on the bare block device.

Now that you have added a partition table, you have likely overwritten / trashed the first part of your root filesystem - when you reboot you'll likely see an error.

Remember that `/dev/sda` refers to the *whole* device, from the beginning to end... `/dev/sda1` refers to a smaller region of this same device. They are not two separate entities, but rather `sda1` is a subset of `sda`.

According to the diagram below:

- Your filesystem is on the green (bare block device)
- You've just written the red partition table (I'm guessing MBR) over the beginning of your filesystem.
- If you were to use `mkfs` on the orange section (aka a "*partition*"), then you would be further destroying your data that exists on the underlying block device (green).

[image: block device layout]

When you do an install, I recommend that you always make a partition table ([MBR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record) or [GPT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table), it's up to you), and put your filesystems in a *partition*, not on the bare block device.

---

As a side note, if you had used partitions, then you could get rid of `/dev/sdb`, and put your swap on a partition that resides on `/dev/sda`...

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  That does make sense and I was considering in my mind that seen as it was the main disk of my system that i was partitioning , I hope it does not affect the files already on that disk. But when fdisk offers you the first free blocks as the suggested place to start the partition, I was thinking that this must be the point on the disk where there was no files stored so it would be free/safe to use.
I will delete the partition now and hopefully don't see any errors.  
Thanks again for your help - Lesson learned there.

Comment: The "_first free block_" will be with respect to the other partitions already inplace... not with respect to any data that exists ouside the partition table's knowledge.

Comment: I suspect that your files are **_okay for now_**... but if you need to keep them, then **_back them up now_**, to storage outside the VM... it will be much more difficult to get them back once you shutdown / reboot the VM.

Answer (score 0):

Its simple, what u have done is terminated the current terminal, so solution is :
remove the particular harddisk ie SATA etc... and add it again with preferred disk size. It worked for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).