# How to mount the disk properly?

Tags: linux, partitioning, mount

There are three partitions in my disk-b `/dev/sdb`, I deleted them all with `sudo fdisk /dev/sdb` and created a new partition on it.I find that `/dev/sdb`  can't be mounted properly,reboot and check again.

```
sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sdb: 232.9 GiB, 250059350016 bytes, 488397168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: E4B9D815-14F7-4957-B8D4-561B0EEDADFA

Device     Start       End   Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdb1   2048 486541311 486539264  232G Linux filesystem


Disk /dev/sda: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 4817B004-6C28-4C6D-97FD-DA68A7F57544

Device          Start        End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1        2048     923647    921600   450M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda2      923648    1128447    204800   100M EFI System
/dev/sda3     1128448    1161215     32768    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda4     1161216  408796449 407635234 194.4G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda5   408797184  409862143   1064960   520M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda6   409864192  441114623  31250432  14.9G Linux swap
/dev/sda7   441114624  636426239 195311616  93.1G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda8   831739904 1417676799 585936896 279.4G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda9   636426240  831739903 195313664  93.1G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda10 1417676800 1612988415 195311616  93.1G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda11 1612988416 1633959935  20971520    10G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda12 1633959936 1953524389 319564454 152.4G Linux filesystem

Partition table entries are not in disk order.
```

`Ubuntu 20.04 LTS amd64` is the previous label for my `/dev/sdb1` , I have already deleted it.

[image]

```
cat /etc/fstab
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda7 during installation
UUID=61a48dca-cae3-40af-b89b-39eb813daa55 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=A4BB-9CC3  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda6 during installation
UUID=7827ba01-973d-4d54-a447-732843bd5a50  none            swap    sw              0       0


#mount /dev/sda4 
UUID=0042E54842E54350  /media/debian/0042E54842E54350      ntfs-3g   rw,user,exec,umask=000 0 0
#mount /dev/sda5 
UUID=C0FC6E55FC6E462E  /media/debian/C0FC6E55FC6E462E      ntfs-3g   rw,user,exec,umask=000 0 0
```

How to fix it?

Comment: What do you mean you can't mount `/dev/sdb`? I mean I guess you could try forcing the kernel to write a filesystem to a raw disk, but did you mean that you couldn't try mount the partition `/dev/sdb1` of `/dev/sdb`?

Comment: Have you tried something like `mkfs.ext3 /dev/sdb1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an important distinction to make here: partitions are *not* filesystems.

A "*partition*" is simply an allocation of contiguous space on a storage device - it's possible to write anything you like to this storage, but it is just a collection of bytes with no particular layout or structure.

A "*filesystem*" is a complex data structure that is stored to permit flexible allocation of storage and access to entities (i.e: "*files*") in a logical and ordered way (i.e: using "*directories*").

Once you've changed the partitioning of a device, you'll also need to write a new filesystem. These steps are often merged into one operation in GUIs, particularly in Windows' UI.

Here, you should look into one of the following tools according to what you're after:

- `mkfs.ext2` / `mkfs.ext3` / [`mkfs.ext4`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mkfs.ext4) - Make an ext2/3/4 system
- [`mkfs.ntfs`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mkfs.ntfs) - Make an NTFS filesystem
- [`mkfs.vfat`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mkfs.vfat) - Make a FAT32 filesystem
- [`mkfs.exfat`](https://manpages.debian.org/wheezy/exfat-utils/mkfs.exfat.8) - Make an [exFAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ExFAT) filesystem

For example:

```
mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdb1
```

---

See some of my other answers on the topic for more information:

- [Partition Help - /dev/sda1 is apparently in use by the system; will not make a filesystem here](https://superuser.com/a/1551728/707676)
- [Resizing VirtualBox's disk size](https://superuser.com/a/1341789/707676)

Comment: @gronostaj No problem - thanks for picking me up on it... improved clarity is always good.

Answer (score 0):

Add filesystem on the new created partition `/dev/sdb1`.

```
sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdb1
```

Rename the lable,delete the previous lable for the partition `/dev/sdb1`.

```
sudo e2label /dev/sdb1 othername
```

Comment: A little explanation will take this from a possibly informative comment to an actual answer.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/985112)

Comment: 1. I have already accepted  Attie's post as a formal answer.

Comment: 2.  I solve the remained issue myself--rename lable's name for the partition.

Comment: 3. I have the right to write a whole steps.

Comment: 4. That just proves this is a comment. Please read our help section to learn how this site works. Superuser isn't a forum, its a QA site with questions, answers, and comments. Please recognize the reasons and benefits of that, and respect it.